# Magento 2: Short Description label shown as "none" on product page

Tags: magento2, layout, product-view, extend

For some reason the label of the short description is shown as "none" in frontend's product page just before the short description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended the `catalog_product_view.xml` with this:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.overview">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

The location for the **new file**:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete Webninja's response, you should add a `translate="false"` if you want to handle multi-langage and if your `at_label` = `none`.

You will end up with this code to add in the `catalog_product_view.xml` :

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.overview">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_label" translate="false" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Here is the reason why you may have to add this parameter :

In the native file `catalog_product_view.xml` (in Magento_Catalog module), you will see that `product.info.overview` block is defined that way :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Unlike other usage of `product/view/attribute.phtml`, The `at_label` argument here is being translated.

Now looking at the file `product/view/attribute.phtml`, we'll see that this could be problematic :

```
<?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
```

If you have a translation of the "none" string in another langage, the condition will turn to true, and your translation of "none" will be displayed right before your attribute as a label.