# Magento2 - Short Description titled as "none" in Product view

Tags: magento2

The attribute "Short Description" is titled "none" in the product view. How can I change that title or remove it?

Comment: Have you set from product attribute title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Way,**

You can set title from backend for short_description in detail page.

In Backend,

> Stores -> Attributes -> Product

Click on short_description row from list of attributes.

**Click on Left sidebar Tab, Manage Labels** and

**Set Title in text field from 
Default Store View section.**

**2nd way,**

Override **catalog_product_view.xml** file in your theme,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.overview">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
     <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
  </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: I actually did that. I set a German title for it, but it doesnt work.. (for all other attributes it seems to work tho..)

Comment: run commnad, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE

Comment: This actually didnt do anything.. I heard you need to edit the file "catalog_product_view.xml"..  I tried it like here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141263/magento-2-short-description-label-shown-as-none-on-product-page . It did work,  but other things randomly disappeard from catalog product view then...